# Build Java service application in Jenkins with Servlet / JSP dependencies from Tomcat

Tags: java, jenkins, tomcat, deployment, ant

**I have five servers (load balanced) running a Java SOAP service in Tomcat.** One way deployments can be done is by fetching the code from a repo and building on the same server machine using ANT which eventually copies the war file into Tomcat's webapps dir.

Trying to do this using Jenkins. There is a dedicated machine running Jenkins with Java and ANT installed. **Plan is to build and package into a war file that will then be *copied by Jenkins to each production server's Tomcat webapps dir*.**

Trying to build using the ANT target results in not finding Servlet and related dependencies provided by Tomcat which is mentioned in the ANT build file. As a quick solution installed Tomcat on the machine running Jenkins so that the files are found and the build process succeeds. This works running the ANT target on console. But, trying to run it from Jenkins fails with error:

```
IO error scanning directory '<path to TOMCAT_HOME>/lib'
```

All machines are running Linux servers.

Comment: Probably based on the location you are executing `ant` makes a difference.

Comment: Does the account that's running the Jenkins agent have read access to the tomcat 'lib ` directory? Usually it's locked down. Can you pull the jars from a repository or staging location?

Comment: When I am running the `ant` command from console, I am in the project's root directory. The project itself is in `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/`. The build succeeds this way. It fails when Jenkins is running the same `ant` build command.

Comment: @IanW, you are right. Jenkins user did not have read permission in the `lib` dir. `chmod 754` allowed it to include the `jar`s in the build and `.war` file was created as expected.

Comment: Made advice an answer, but be better  to delete the Q since the solution was trivial and the cause "human error"

Answer (score 0):

Does the account that's running the Jenkins agent have read access to the tomcat 'lib ` directory? Usually it's locked down. Can you pull the jars from a repository or staging location?